# SAPUI5: How to achieve a flip animated page navigation?

Tags: sapui5

I want to implement a similar way of page navigation as shown in the below link (sap.m demo app).  Like that, when I click a header button, I want to show another page like code is shown in this example, if I click back it is returning back to the same page with same state maintained.

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/explored/index.html#/sample/tableViewSettingsDialog

Comment: I managed to figure what you mean but you could really invest few more seconds into more precise questions. Will also help you get more/better answers.

Comment: I have done this using routes and am not asking about transition types

Answer (score 3):

**Flip in UI5 Mobile**

Using a regular sap.m.NavigationContainer you can provide "flip" as the `sTransitionName` and you'll get the desired transition:
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainer.html#to

**Flip in combination with Routes**

Not sure on how to do this in combination with Routes. The NavContainer and transition concept is something specific to UI5 Mobile.

Anyways while using routes it should be easy to achieve a flip animation with CSS: http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip